# np.savetxt not appending even when file is still open

Tags: python, numpy, append

Edit!!!
 In the end I was able to write this with the while loop that I wanted and saved to correct output folder while it being appending.

Solution:

```
tempfilename=keyname+'_trimmed.fastq'
TempSavelocation="./fastqs/"+tempfilename
f=open(TempSavelocation,'ab')
icounter=0
while icounter < len(tempid): 
    with open(TempSavelocation,'ab') as f:
    # Creating the type of a structure                  
    structuredArr=np.array([tempid[icounter],tempseq[icounter],"+", tempqc[icounter]])
    np.savetxt(f, structuredArr, fmt=['%s'])  
    icounter=icounter+1 
f.close()
```

This gave me the correct output, I also tried with the for-loop but a while is what I was most useful for my particular problem.

Problem:

The issue is that when I run npsavetext it is not working correctly, I initially had this as a while loop (which would be the most ideal in my mind, to cycle through a list that has matched list and append them into a single file)

Below is my code:

```
atable=['a','b','b','a','b','b']
f=open(tempfilename,'ab')
f.write(b"\n")
with open(tempfilename,'ab') as f:
    for s in atable: 
        structuredArr=np.array([s,"+"])    
        np.savetxt("./fastqs/"+tempfilename, structuredArr, delimiter=' ', fmt=['%s'])  
f.close()
```

Expected result is below:

```
a
+
b
+
b
+
a
+
b
+
b
```

Actual result is

```
+
b
```

Ideally what I am trying to actually do is 
below:

```
icounter=0
    f=open(tempfilename,'ab'
    while icounter < len(tempid): 
        with open(tempfilename,'ab') as f:
            # Creating the type of a structure
          structuredArr=np.array([tempid[icounter],tempseq[icounter],"+",tempqc[icounter]])
            np.savetxt("./fastqs/"+tempfilename, structuredArr, delimiter=' ', fmt=['%s'])  
            f.write("\n")
        icounter=icounter+1 
    f.close()
```

I though that the latter probably didn't append because of my while loop.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Use a file object opened for append instead of the file name in "np.savetxt".

Comment: @MichaelButscher I tried changing to the following....         np.savetxt(TempSavelocation, structuredArr, delimiter=' ', fmt=['%s']) , but still did not append.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, Thank you, that worked as long as I saved my TempSavelocation with the full path

Answer (score 0):

When using `with open`, do that saving with the indented block.

```
In [329]: atable=['a','b','b','a','b','b'] 
     ...: with open('abtest.csv','ab') as f: 
     ...:     for s in atable:  
     ...:         structuredArr=np.array([s,"+"])     
     ...:         np.savetxt(f, structuredArr, delimiter=' ', fmt=['%s'])   
     ...:                                                                                
In [330]: cat abtest.csv                                                                 
a
+
b
+
b
+
a
+
b
+
b
+
```